# Stellar payments query

Tags: java, paypal

I am unable to execute the example payment query program on the  official website. Here is my code, almost same with the sample. Here is the [official website](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html).

```
public class TransCheck {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
    KeyPair account = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GARUMRUP37CPOGQQALSXBDQQS6SUDDPKGLGFERH6PIJEHWQY5IAVZQDL");

    // Create an API call to query payments involving the account.
    // server.payments() Returns PaymentsRequestBuilder instance.
    // forAccount() Builds request to GET /accounts/{account}/payments - Account for which to get payments
    PaymentsRequestBuilder paymentsRequest = server.payments().forAccount(account);

    // If some payments have already been handled, start the results from the
    // last seen payment. (See below in `handlePayment` where it gets saved.)
    String lastToken = loadLastPagingToken();
    if (lastToken != null) {
      paymentsRequest.cursor(lastToken);
    }

    // `stream` will send each recorded payment, one by one, then keep the
    // connection open and continue to send you new payments as they occur.

    paymentsRequest.stream(new EventListener <OperationResponse>(){
      @Override
      public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) {
        // Record the paging token so we can start from here next time.
        savePagingToken(payment.getPagingToken());

        // The payments stream includes both sent and received payments. We only
        // want to process received payments here.
        if (payment instanceof PaymentOperationResponse) {
          if (((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getTo().equals(account)) {
            return;
          }

          String amount = ((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getAmount();

          Asset asset = ((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getAsset();
          String assetName;
          if (asset.equals(new AssetTypeNative())) {
            assetName = "lumens";
          } else {
            StringBuilder assetNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            assetNameBuilder.append(((AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum) asset).getCode());
            assetNameBuilder.append(":");
            assetNameBuilder.append(((AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum) asset).getIssuer().getAccountId());
            assetName = assetNameBuilder.toString();
          }

          StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
          output.append(amount);
          output.append(" ");
          output.append(assetName);
          output.append(" from ");
          output.append(((PaymentOperationResponse) payment).getFrom().getAccountId());
          System.out.println(output.toString());
        }
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

There are two errors in my code. First, the method: `loadLastPagingToken()` is undefined and I cannot find the detail of this method. Second, when I want to create a `new EventListener <OperationResponse>()` the IDE told that

> The type EventListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

I really do not know why. Could you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of your import statement.

Try

import org.stellar.sdk.requests.EventListener;

instead of

import java.util.EventListener;

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, the intent of `loadLastPagingToken` is to fetch a bookmark from which you wish the stream to start. As you are running this for the first time and don't have such a value, you should set it to `null`.  Later, if you are building the ability to restart a stream you will need to know the token from the last processed page. The method `loadLastPagingToken` is given here as a stub for you to implement if you need it.

Your second issue has been answered by CR-Soneso. You have imported the wrong `EventListener` class.

If you have further questions on Stellar, you may find faster answers to your questions on the [dedicated Stellar stackexchange](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/) (currently in beta).