# Receiving payment code is not working in stellar network

Tags: java, paypal, payment

I have just recently started analysis on **[Stellar](https://www.stellar.org/.)**

Also from below link , I have created account and also created test account using friend-bot.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html

Then I have run the **Java** code for making payments using **[Sending Payment](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html)** operation.

Also they have given another code for **[Receiving Payments](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html#receive-payments)**.

While running that code , it gets terminated. I have also debug that code in Eclipse. It reached to  **paymentsRequest.stream** line but it is not calling **onEvent** method.

I have also referred below reference link and follow the answer but still it is not working.

[Stellar payments query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788073/stellar-payments-query)

Can anyone tell me how to run this code which continuously receive the payments and maintain the logs on console. ?